# Сортировка поднятых тревог не только по времени?

Tags: предложение, страница-учётной-записи, тревоги

**Дано:**

В данный момент если из профиля посмотреть список поднятых тревог, то он представлен в виде списка отсортированного по времени. И каждая тревог со всей о ней инфой идёт одной строкой (почти одной) с такой разметкой, что кажется, будто она "поехала" (особенно криво, ИМХО, дата смотрится). При этом если тревога поднята по поводу коммента (например коммент "`пых это фейл`" с тревогой "`слишком слабо обоснованный`"; см 1 тревогу на скриншоте) то никакой инфы о том, что это коммент - нема.

**Вопросы:**

1. Есть ли какие-то способы получить более детальную инфу о поднятых тревогах?
2. Можно ли отсортировать как-то тревоги? Хотя бы по ожиданию?
3. Будут ли улучшения вёрстки этой страницы?

**Скриншот:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: только что заметил - добавили фильтр по типу и статусу тревог